# Precise definition of epsilon-ball

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, terminology

My textbook gives the following definition: "For each $\epsilon>0$, the $\epsilon$-ball about a point $x$ in a metric space $M$ is the set $\{y\in M:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$."

Is this correct? Because this sounds as if $\epsilon$ is just a dummy variable, and that there is such a thing as, say, a "5-ball" meaning $\{y\in M:d(x,y)<5\}$.

Shouldn't the correct definition be something along the lines of "The $\epsilon$-ball about a point $x$ in a metric space $M$ is the set $\{y\in M:$ for each $\epsilon >0, d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$." ?

Comment: It would be a great idea to prove the claim given in the answers below as an exercise: show that for any $x \in M$, your definition leads to $\{x\}$.

Comment: Your definition gives the set $\{y\in M\mid d(x,y)=0\}$, since if $d$ is smaller than each positive real number then it must be $0$. In a pseudometric space this is not necessarily the singleton $\{x\}$. In a metric space, however, it is due to the definition of a metric.

Comment: @StefanH. Thanks!

Comment: There is indeed a $5$-ball, defined just the way you defined it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; in fact, the set you mention consists only of the point $x$, which is certainly not what we want!

Perhaps better is to define *an* $\epsilon$-ball, rather than *the* $\epsilon$-ball. Each $\epsilon$ ball is different if $\epsilon$ is different.

You're right that the $\epsilon$ is somewhat arbitrary. Usually what we want to say is something like, "The set $S$ contains an $\epsilon$-ball around $x$," where we don't care what the precise $\epsilon$ is.  The key is that it can be as small as you like.

Here's a good example: take a point $p$ in the plane which is on the $y$-axis, and let $S$ be the right half plane, i.e. $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0 \}$. Then we can say that *for all* $\epsilon>0$, there is a point $s\in S$ such that $d(p,s)<\epsilon$. Any particular point in $S$ will be a finite distance away, but the point is that $S$ is as close to $p$ as we like. Another way of saying this is, "$x$ is in $S$-closure."

$\epsilon$ is used as a sort of shorthand. When someone says "$\epsilon$" in mathematics, everyone knows, "oh, she means a positive number that we can think of as arbitrarily small". Of course there is no single number that is arbitrarily small, but usually we are talking about a condition that holds *for all* $\epsilon >0$. So *no mattter how small you go*, the condition still holds. This is the case when we talk about limits and continuity, for example.

When you study metric spaces (if you haven't already), you'll learn that you can give $\mathbb{R}^n$ many different norms. In these norms, the distance between two points may be something different than in the norm we're used to. And yet, all the definitions of continuity, limits, etc. stay the same! How can that be? It is because these norms are *equivalent*, meaning that, although all the individual distances are different, they both get arbitrarily small in the same places. So for instance, if you have a sequence going to zero in one norm, it will still go to zero in the other norm. So all the definitions using "$\forall \epsilon>0$" still hold in any norm you like!

Comment: Thank you! Then why in the world is the symbol/name "epsilon" always used in the definition of epsilon-ball? Why not alpha- or beta- or p-ball? I mean, the $\epsilon$ typically used in analysis definitions isn't an arbitrary $\epsilon$, is it?

Comment: @Ryan I clarified a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I guess what I meant (in my above comment) was that, usually in definitions, epsilon is used to indicate arbitrary smallness. But here, technically, epsilon does not refer to an arbitarily small number, but in an *any* arbitrary number, i.e. it is used as a mere dummy variable.  I guess your point is that in practice nobody really talks about a 5-ball, and epsilon-ball is typically used to refer to an arbitrarily small ball (even though technically, it *is* possible to have a 1000-ball). I don't know what I would do without Stackexchange.

Comment: Right, it's fine to speak about the  $2$-ball, and the $\alpha$-ball, for example. The definition uses $\epsilon$ because "an arbitrarily small number" is the context in which we usually have need for a ball.

Comment: correction: "....but in fact *any* arbitrary number...."

Comment: It makes sense for any arbitrary positive number (the $-1$-ball is $\emptyset$)

Comment: @Ryan: To answer your "why $\epsilon$?" question, although I speak with no official authority. In the usual $\delta$-$\epsilon$ context: Think of $\epsilon$ as Error, and the obligatory $\delta$ as the change allowed in the independent variable for the function variation to stay within the desired error.

Answer (score 4):

Your first impression is correct. There is a $5$-ball and a ${\sqrt 2}$-ball and a $0.000001$-ball. Your second suggestion would amount to the singleton set $\{x\}$.

Comment: It's very helpful to see these concrete examples. Thank you.