# Definition of accumulation point

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, terminology

I have here a definition of **accumulation point**: A point $x$ in a metric space $M$ is called an accumulation point of $A \subset M$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains some point of $A$ distinct from $x$.

The definition seems vague to me; how to translate the condition in it?

I) For each neighbourhood $N$ of $x$, there exists some $y\in A$ such that $y\in N$ and $y\neq x.$

or

II) There exists some $y\in A$ such that for each neighbourhood $N$ of $x$, $y\in N$ and $y\neq x.$

Comment: Definition I) looks like what you're looking for to me.

Comment: II is too strong. Also remember my comment here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454245/precise-definition-of-epsilon-ball#comment976996_454245. It is only possible in pseudometric spaces.

Comment: "Accumulation point" is just another term for "limit point". They are the same thing. Limit point is far more common terminology. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I) is the appropriate choice. If you want to be completely formal you might want to add a definition of what a neighborhood of $x$ is (in terms of the metric on the space).

II) does not work because it requires that $y$ belongs to every neighborhood of $x$. By the [definition of a metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) this can only be if $y=x$ which conflicts with the rest of the definition.

EDIT: (Drawing a picture in these cases can help quite a bit) Let $d$ denote the metric on $M$ and $B_r:=\{y\in M:d(x,y)<r\}$ denote the open ball centred around $x$ of radius $r$. Suppose that $y\in B_r$ for all $r>0$. Then, $d(x,y)=0$. Otherwise there exists an $r>0$ such that $d(x,y)=r$. However, this contradicts our assumption that $y
\in B_r$. Now, by the definition of the metric, $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Thanks. But why isn't there a point (other than x itself) that belongs to every neighbourhood of x? I'm not able to infer this from the definition of metric.

Comment: You're welcome -- see edit (let me know if there is anything unclear).

Comment: Thanks again. This part I don't follow:  "Otherwise there exists an r>0 such that d(x,y)=r. However, this contradicts our assumption that y∈Br"

Comment: So a metric is a non-negative function, hence $d(x,y)\neq 0$ implies that $d(x,y)>0$. In turn, $d(x,y)>0$ implies that there is some real number greater than $0$, lets call it $r$, such that $d(x,y)=r$. If this is so, then $y$ does not belong to $B_r$, the open ball of radius $r$ (by definition, the ball does not contain points $z$ such that $d(x,z)=r$ and, in particular, it does not contain $y$). Did that help?

Comment: @jkn Yes, I would have taken $r/2$ but $r$ is just fine too.

Comment: I think that the only way you could "improve" (in the sense of removing ambiguity) the definition would be by adding a definition of a neighbourhood in terms of the space and the metric. As Sh3ljohn mentions the fact that you state that "for every neighbourhood $N$ there exists a $y$ such that ...", already implies that $y$ depends on $N$, in the sense that for different $N$s there might be different $y$s. Thus you don't need to make it explicit (however, it doesn't do any real harm apart from making the definition slightly more cumbersome).

Comment: No, my suggested "improvement" was with reference to the original given definition, not the two interpretations (disambiguations) I gave following it. In it, it doesn't seem to be clear whether one ought to choose the neighbourhood first, or to choose the point distinct from x first.  Thank you your help!

Comment: In my opinion, the ambiguity is removed by the order of the clauses in the phrase. I mean that "every neighbourhood" comes before "some point" implying that for each neighbourhood we have to find some point in it, not that we have to find a common point that works for all neighbourhoods. The latter is what you ask for if you switch the clauses round: "...if there is some point contained in every neighbourhood of x...".

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if $\forall r > 0,\ \exists y\in A,\ y\neq x,\ d(x,y) < r$. Note that $x$ is not necessarily an element of $A$ (in which case the condition $y\neq x$ is redundant).

Comment: By the way, don't you think the wording of the definition ought to be improved? One shouldn't have to infer the meaning of a definition; that's like creating a lemma/theorem. Is this edit okay?  "A point x in a metric space M is called an accumulation point of A⊂M if every neighbourhood **N** of x contains some point **(depending on N)** of A distinct from x."

Comment: @Ryan Adding "depending on N" is redundant, since you already said "every neighborhood N contains some point". Rather than "every", I would say "any", but you've got the idea.. Neighborhoods aren't necessarily countable.

Comment: @Ryan To answer your concern about "inferring the meaning of a definition", assuming you are talking about the definition of "neighborhood", I sincerely don't agree with you. Actually, in any proper lesson on the subject, the neighborhood of a point should be defined  after the definition of open/closed sets, after that of a metric, and before that of an accumulation point (which leads to the study of series and compactness by the way). The point is; no inference needed, we simply build up on previously defined concepts.

Comment: Thanks. No I wasn't talking abt the definition of n'hood! I mean, "every neighbourhood of x contains _some point of A distinct from x_" could concievably be interpreted as "_for some point p of A distinct from x_, every neighbourhood of x contains p."  Regarding your other point, baby Rudin actually treats "neighbourhood" as the more fundamental concept, defines "interior point" in terms of that, then defines "open set" in terms of interior point! OTOH, my prescribed textbook does it the "topologically sensible" way, as you approve of. -)

Comment: @Ryan Interesting... For the sentences, I would answer that maths are at least as precise as anyone could think of, and the ambiguity of a sentence should not put the formal definition in the shade. We can discuss the meaning of words forever, but the definition in my post is clear and unambiguous. I would argue that it's clear to me that in your second sentence, you're trying to find out if any neighborhood of $x$ contains a specific point (not possible if it's not $x$ btw..), whereas in the first one, you're trying to find out if they all intersect $A$. It sounds very different to me.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, and that was my initial interpretation too, until I tied myself in knots worrying about how it would sound to someone who was reading the sentence cold.